# How can I print the variable of a singleton?

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {

    static let user = User()
    private override init() {}

    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?
    var profileImage: UIImage?
    var profileImageDownloadUrl: String?
    var partyStatus: Bool?

}
```

In my first viewcontroller I did:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let user = User.user
    user.name = "Bob"
}
```

In my second viewcontroller I did:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let user = User.user
    print(user.name)
}
```

I thought the second viewcontroller should print "Bob" but it returns as nil. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the `viewDidLoad` of the 2nd view controller is being called after the `viewDidLoad` of the 1st?

Comment: @rmaddy I’m positive. I think it might be a concurrency issue with how I am storing the values for properties in my Singleton

Comment: Your code here is fine. It must be sth else.

Comment: Unrelated but there's no need (that can be seen here) for `User` to extend `NSObject`.

Comment: Add print commands in both of the view controllers and check which one runs first... I guess in your case the second one is running first.

Comment: How u are navigating to second viewcontroller because if first VC is called then it will als show value of User in another VC

Comment: I don't think this is a concurrency issue, based on the code, it seems like  both are in the main thread. Just initialise the name as "abcd" while defining it in the class. Add log statements / breakpoints.

Comment: Where are the two VCs loaded from? `viewDidLoad()` is not the same as `viewWillAppear()`, and if the two VCs are loaded at the "same" time, the order of execution of  the 2 `viewDidLoad()`s can't be guaranteed...